# send signed transaction from smart contract

Tags: solidity, contract-design, smart-contract-wallets, sendsignedtransaction, meta-transactions

I need to know if it is possible to implement a smart contract to send signed transaction (signed with metamask). The user that sign the transaction must pay the fees.
All examples that I'm reading is to implement gasless transactions (meta-transactions) and GSN v2 (https://docs.opengsn.org/).

The objective is create a smart contract to do specific business logic before to do the DAI token transaction.

Thanks

Comment: With metamask you can sign a message and send a transaction (the user will have to accept two confirmation dialogs). It is not clear what's the purpose, a contract will never be able to impersonate and act as a user. Some tokens allow [EIP 2612 signed approvals](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2612), but it is a specific purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a [modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44982437/what-does-a-modifier-do-in-solidity) on your smart contract to perform those actions prior to making transactions, if those business logics don't go successfully you can just revert the transactions.

Comment: then, do I need to extend the DAI contract to add new business logic?